How to make the Binding of a TextField take an optional Int?
I have a SwiftData model with 2 optionals:
@Model
class MySet: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int?
    var reps: Int?

I pass an object of this set down to this view where its reps and weight can be 0 if the set has not been edited yet:
struct SetEditor: View {
    
    var currentIndex: Int
    
    @Bindable var myset: MySet

Then I created an extension to allow me to bind it to a TextField:
//extensions to create bindings so the Textfield can directly manipulate the object
extension MySet {

    var weightBinding: Binding<Int?> {
        Binding<Int?>(
            get: { self.weight },
            set: { value in
                if let value {  //unwrapping the optional that the user entered and only setting it to weight if it isnt nil
                    self.weight = value
                }
            }
        )
    }
    var repBinding: Binding<Int?> {
        Binding<Int?>(
            get: { self.reps },
            set: { value in
                if let value {
                    self.reps = value
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
}

Then I use it in a TextField like so :
  TextField(
                    "\(myset.weight ?? 0)",
                    value: myset.weightBinding, formatter: NumberFormatter()
                   )

this all worked perfectly fine before I made reps and weight optional (when a new set was created it was set to 0 0), but I wanted to save the user the step of having to clear the 0 to start typing, now when I add new numbers and click away from the TextField it no longer saves the number typed in it just reverst to nil nil, is there a way to fix this?

why do you keep asking questions when you already know the answer, then post the answer within minutes?

@workingdogsupportUkraine answering your own questions is completely fine. Other users might also encounter the same issue in the future, so asking a question even if you already know the answer can be helpful for the community. Of course, both the question and the answer have to be high quality and make sense to future readers as well.

The issue was using NumberFormatter, to use Optional Binding Int? in TextFields in SwiftUi you must use the following:
TextField(
                    "\(myset.weight ?? 0)",
                    value: myset.weightBinding, format: .number
                   )

Happy Coding

Using a NumberFormatter would be more correct. This uses Int.description to format the number, which is completely wrong in most locales on Earth.
